# Add timing of jquery

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I need help adding a 2-second delay to the load of the below;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.magnificPopup.open({items: {src: '#my-form'},type: 'inline'}, 0);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the native `setTimeout` function in JavaScript and apply your function as a callback:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout($.magnificPopup.open({items: {src: '#my-form'},type: 'inline'}, 0),2000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
         setTimeout(function(){ $.magnificPopup.open({items: {src: '#my-form'},type: 'inline'}, 0); }, 2000);
       });
    </script>
```